# Perl kill(0, $pid) in Windows always returning 1

Tags: windows, perl, process

I'm trying to make a Perl script that will run a set of other programs in Windows. I need to be able to capture the stdout, stderr, and exit code of the process, and I need to be able to see if a process exceeds it's allotted execution time.
Right now, the pertinent part of my code looks like:

```
...
        $pid = open3($wtr, $stdout, $stderr, $command);
        if($time < 0){
            waitpid($pid, 0);
            $return = $? >> 8;
            $death_sig = $? & 127;
            $core_dump = $? & 128;
        }
        else{
            # Do timeout stuff, currently not working as planned
            print "pid: $pid\n";
            my $elapsed = 0;
            #THIS LOOP ONLY TERMINATES WHEN $time > $elapsed ...?
            while(kill 0, $pid and $time > $elapsed){
                Time::HiRes::usleep(1000);  # sleep for milliseconds
                $elapsed += 1;
                $return = $? >> 8;
                $death_sig = $? & 127;
                $core_dump = $? & 128;
            }
            if($elapsed >= $time){
                $status = "FAIL";
                print $log "TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED\n";
            }
        }
        #these lines are needed to grab the stdout and stderr in arrays so 
        #  I may reuse them in multiple logs
        if(fileno $stdout){
            @stdout = <$stdout>;
        }
        if(fileno $stderr){
            @stderr = <$stderr>;
        }
...
```

Everything is working correctly if `$time = -1` (no timeout is needed), but the system thinks that `kill 0, $pid` is always 1. This makes my loop run for the entirety of the time allowed.

Some extra details just for clarity:

- This is being run on Windows.
- I know my process does terminate because I have get all the expected output.
- Perl version: This is perl, v5.10.1 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
  (with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail) Copyright 1987-2009, Larry Wall
  Binary build 1007 [291969] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
  Built Jan 26 2010 23:15:11
- I appreciate your help :D

*For that future person who may have a similar issue*
I got the code to work, here is the modified code sections:

```
        $pid = open3($wtr, $stdout, $stderr, $command);
        close($wtr);
        if($time < 0){
            waitpid($pid, 0);
        }
        else{
            print "pid: $pid\n";
            my $elapsed = 0;
            while(waitpid($pid, WNOHANG) <= 0 and $time > $elapsed){
                Time::HiRes::usleep(1000);  # sleep for milliseconds
                $elapsed += 1;
            }

            if($elapsed >= $time){
                $status = "FAIL";
                print $log "TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED\n";
            }
        }
        $return = $? >> 8;
        $death_sig = $? & 127;
        $core_dump = $? & 128;
        if(fileno $stdout){
            @stdout = <$stdout>;
        }
        if(fileno $stderr){
            @stderr = <$stderr>;
        }
        close($stdout);
        close($stderr);
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals. Perhaps you shouldn't use them to figure out if a process is running.

Comment: kill - Returns the number of processes successfully signaled (which is not necessarily the same as the number actually killed).

Comment: @ikegami, [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) says Win32 implements `kill(0, ...)` semantics.

Comment: @Ron Bergin, I'm not trying to kill the process, I'm trying to check it's status/if it's running. So if it recieves the signal it should be running, correct?

Comment: Actually, it says "if $sig is 0 and the specified process exists, it returns true without actually terminating it." The process still exists since you still have handles to it. Try closing/undefing the file handles when when you reap.

Comment: That sounds like that might be the answer I'm looking for. Let me look into it

Comment: @ikegami, the next few lines of my code are going to be added to the question, and I'll give a little detail, but I'm not sure how I could go about closing my file handles earlier.

Comment: When `waitpid` succeeds. It's just a suggestion. I don't know if it'll work.

Comment: @ikegami, I don't want to `waitpid` because I need to terminate the process if it didn't execute in it's time slot (that code hasn't been done yet).

Comment: huh? You do `waitpid`. Actually, why are you suing `kill` at all? Why not using a nohang `waitpid`?

Comment: if `$time < 0` (aka they want the process to have no time limit)

Comment: See the rest of the comment...

Comment: That might be doing the trick, thanks a lot. The only issue that leaves me with is a bad return code for one of the calls, but I should be able to figure that one out.

Comment: Problems in code in the update: You access `$?` even when you don't use `waitpid` (so it contains garbage). You deadlock if the child fill up the buffer of the pipe on its STDOUT. Same goes for STDERR. (These deadlocks will result in a "false" timeout.) You don't kill the child on timeout. You should use [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run).

Comment: For the first half, I do use waitpid in both the if and the else. The only time I don't is when it exceeds the time limit, so it is ok if that contains garbage. I will look into using IPC::Run, but I will stop updating this so that my original question and answer doesn't get overdone. Thank you for all of your help. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `kill 0`, use [`waitpid $pid, WNOHANG`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html):

```
use POSIX qw( WNOHANG );

if (waitpid($pid, WNOHANG) > 0) {
   # Process has ended. $? is set.
   ...
}
```

Comment: there's a typo on the first line: `WHOHANG`->`WNOHANG`