# Checking child process status in Perl

Tags: perl, parent-child

I'm having some trouble getting the exit status of child processes. For some reason the kill 0, $pid way doesn't seem to work. I'm running the following script on a Unix machine:

```
for ( my $count = 1; $count <= 2; $count++) {
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid) {
    # parent
    push(@childs, $pid);
    } elsif ($pid == 0) {
            # child
            sleep(10);
            exit 0;
    } else {
            die "couldnt fork: $!\n";
    }
```

}

```
foreach (@childs) {

if (kill 0, $_){
    print "$_ is running...\n";
}
else {
    print "$_ is complete\n";
}
```

}

```
sleep (20);
foreach (@childs) {
if (kill 0, $_){
    print "$_ is running...\n";
}
else {
    print "$_ is complete\n";
}
```

}

The prints I get are:
23285 is running...
23286 is running...
23285 is running...
23286 is running...

Can anybody please explain why this won't work, and maybe suggest a solution or workaround ?
Many thanks!

Comment: use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316547/perl-kill0-pid-in-windows-always-returning-1) instead (in a nutshell: `(waitpid($pid, WNOHANG) > 0)` -> process has ended).

Comment: A `kill 0, $child_pid` tells you if the process can be kill, not that it has stopped. Defunct processes, that is, those which have stopped running, will return true for this. Change the `print`'s to: `print "$_ is killable\n";` and `print "$_ is not killable\n";` and it will respond correctly. Or use `collapsar` suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to fork one child and wait for it I use the [wait()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html) function.

When I have to fork multiple children and wait for them, I use the [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/release/Parallel-ForkManager) module.